# (FOUND) Default factory value in testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have inherited a Laravel 5.3 RESTful API project and still getting my head around it. In the `users` table I removed the `name` column and replaced it with `first_name` and `last_name`. However this has broken the existing tests.

When I run `phpunit` I see the following error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364    Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users`  (`name`, `email`, `password` ...
```

I have searched for seeders, factory files and Google and I can't find how to update the tests to reflect these changes. The only hint I can see is that the error is being created by this line in the test `$user = factory(\App\Models\User::class)->create();`. However I can't see where the fields are configured for tests.

I see people suggest editing config/database.php and setting `strict=false`. However this sounds like a hack and not solving the issue.

Any direction would be very appreciated.

EDIT: Nevermind. I found the file in a pretty obvious place. `Database/factories/`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove columns or add columns in the database directly.
You should create two migrations:

`php artisan make:migration drop_name_from_users_table`

`php artisan make:migration add_first_name_and_last_name_to_users_table`

```
class DropNameFromUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
}

class AddFirstNameAndLastNameToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->dropColumn('first_name');
            $table->dropColumn('last_name');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did use a migration to do that. Although I used one migration file to do so, not two but I don't think that should make any difference.